# Using regex in find command for multiple file types

Tags: regex, bash, file-extension

I am currently using

```
find . -name '*.[cCHh][cC]' -exec grep -nHr "$1" {} ; \
find . -name '*.[cCHh]' -exec grep -nHr "$1" {} ;
```

to search for a string in all files ending with .c, .C, .h, .H, .cc and .CC listed in all subdirectories. But since this includes two commands this feels inefficient.

How can I use a single regex pattern to find .c,.C,.h,.H,.cc and .CC files?

I am using bash on a Linux machine.

Comment: BTW, the argument to `-name` is not a regex, it's a shell expansion.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the boolean OR argument:

```
find . -name '*.[ch]' -o -name '*.[CH]' -o -name '*.cc' -o -name '*.CC'
```

The above searches the current directory and all sub-directories for files that end in:

- `.c`, `.h` OR
- `.C`, `.H` OR
- `.cc` OR
- `.CC`.

Comment: Much more elegant than trying to do it all with regexes.

Comment: This doesn't work if you want to add "-exec". For example "find -name \*.log' -o -name \*.txt -exec cat '{}' \; " It only executes the first -name

Comment: which if for some reason you don't realise is `-o`

Comment: @OutputLogic using `find`s precedence operators ( and ) address this e.g. `find \( -name "*.log" -o -name "*.txt" \) -exec cat {} \;` should mean that `-exec` works as expected.

Comment: rid -- would you mind updating your answer so that casual readers don't miss Briggs' point?

Answer (score 12):

This should work

**Messy**

```
find . -iregex '.*\.\(c\|cc\|h\)' -exec grep -nHr "$1" {} +
```

`-iregex` for case-insensitive regex pattern.

`(c|cc|h)`  (nasty escapes not shown) matches c, cc, or h extensions

---

**Clean**

```
find -regextype "posix-extended" -iregex '.*\.(c|cc|h)' -exec grep -nHr "$1" {} +
```

This will find .Cc and .cC extensions too. You have been warned.

Answer (score 2):

This command works.

```
find -regextype posix-extended -regex '.+\.(h|H|c{1,2}|C{1,2})$'
```

I wish I could use `iregex`. `iregex` would also find `.Cc` and `.cC`. If I could, the command would look like this. Just a bit shorter.

```
find -regextype posix-extended -iregex '.+\.(h|H|c{1,2})$'
```

Answer (score 0):

`find . -regex '.*\.\([chCH]\|cc\|CC\)'`
will find all files with names ending in  .c,.C,.h,.H,.cc and .CC and does not find any that end in .hc, .cC, or .Cc.   In the regex, the first few characters match through the last period in a name, and the parenthesized alternatives match any of the single characters c, h, C, or H, or either of cc or CC.

Note, find's `-regex` and  `-iregex` switches are analogous to `-name` and `-iname`, but the regex-type switches allow regular expressions with `|` for alternative matches.  Like `-iname`,  `-iregex` is case-insensitive.

The (non-functional) form
`find . -name '*.[cCHh][cC]?$'`
given in a previous answer doesn't list any names on my linux system with GNU find 4.4.2.
Another problem with `'*.[cCHh][cC]?$'` as a regex is that it will match names like `abc.Cc` and `xyz.hc` which are not in the set of  .c,.C,.h,.H,.cc and .CC files that you want.

Comment: the first form doesn't work because `?` and `$` are not shell patterns  so they are interpreted literally

Comment: @rid, I edited to point out that `-iregex '.*\.[ch]\|.*\.cc'` does *not* match .cH.  However, I agree that it matches .Cc and .cC and added a `-regex for exact set of extensions